# Gmap v3 event updating symblo markers colors

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-maps-api-3, geometry, marker

I m very new into coding, it s been 3 4 days I m trying to build a website. I started using a wordpress framework, with a nice theme from Elegantthemes called Explora.

This theme is quite limited but I ve managed to change a lot of things in the way it has been built (on front end part only) by changing the responsiveness, the map, the interface and the navigation. Nevertheless, I m stucked on the markers part since my knowledge in coding (jscript and php) is aproximatively around 0.

So here is m y problem :

Withe following code, I intialize markers and I try to give them a circle shape, then, I want to modify the color of the shape while mousing over them ....

```
 
function et_add_marker( marker_order, marker_lat, marker_lng, marker_description ){
            var marker_id = 'et_marker_' + marker_order;

            $et_main_map.gmap3({
                marker : {
                    id : marker_id,
                    latLng : [marker_lat, marker_lng],
                    options: {
                        //icon : "/images/green-marker.png"  //original marker code
                        icon: {
                            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                            fillOpacity: 0.5,
                            //   fillColor: 'ff0000',
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeColor: 'fff000',
                            strokeWeight: 3.0, 
                            scale: Math.floor(Math.random()*21), //random pixel size until get property
                              }
                    },
                    events : {
                        click: function( marker ){
                            if ( et_active_marker ){
                                et_active_marker.setAnimation( null );
                            //  et_active_marker.setIcon( '/images/black-marker.png' );

                            }
                            et_active_marker = marker;

                            marker.setAnimation( google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                            //marker.setIcon( '/images/green-marker.png' );
                                         marker.setOptions({ fillColor: '#0000ff' }); // this is where it doesn t work and I DON T UNDERSTAND WHY 
                            $(this).gmap3("get").panTo( marker.position );

                            $.fn.et_simple_slider.external_move_to( marker_order );
                        },
                        mouseover: function( marker ){
                            $( '#' + marker_id ).css( { 'display' : 'block', 'opacity' : 0 } ).stop(true,true).animate( { bottom : '15px', opacity : 1 }, 500 );
                        },
                        mouseout: function( marker ){
                            $( '#' + marker_id ).stop(true,true).animate( { bottom : '50px', opacity : 0 }, 500, function() {
                                $(this).css( { 'display' : 'none' } );
                            } );
                        }
                    }
                },
                overlay : {
                    latLng : [marker_lat, marker_lng],
                    options : {
                        content : marker_description,
                        offset : {
                            y:-42,
                            x:-122
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I know that Noobs questions are really annoying in seriouses forums like stackoverflow, and I understand that we, noobs, should first go step by step and learn languages before asking people s help, but this thing goes beyond my patience, I would really appreciate to understand why this MARKER.setOptions.({ fillColor: '#0000ff' }); thing is not working. Thank you so much for reading :)

PS : jscript and php are so weird to me lol but they are fascinating

If you want to see the Wsite : http://www.one-world-guide.com

Comment: Ask about particular isolated problems separately. Try to split your problem into smaller and try them step by step on small examples, as you yourself wrote! And post only these small examples. THat way you get much more help.

Comment: Also, if you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code isolating the problem, we can easily tweak it to get it working.

Comment: sure, you're both right :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fillColor` is a property of `Icon`, not `Marker`, so calling `marker.setOptions({fillColor: '0000ff'})` won't work.

Either call setOptions `marker.setOptions({icon: {icon props...}})` or `marker.setIcon({icon props...})`

To avoid having the icon definitions all over the place, you can stick them in variables:

```
var icon = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        fillColor: 'ff0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeColor: 'fff000',
        strokeWeight: 3.0,
        scale: 20
};
// same as icon but with different fillColor
// could use jQuery.extend({}, icon, {fillColor: '0000ff'}) to clone instead
var iconSelected = {
    path: icon.path,
    fillOpacity: icon.fillOpacity,
    fillColor: '0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: icon.strokOpacity,
    strokeColor: icon.strokeColor,
    strokeWeight: icon.strokeWeight,
    scale: icon.scale
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: location,
    icon: icon
});
```

Then switch the icon on click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    this.setIcon(iconSelected);
});
```

This is just using the API directly, not gmap3, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/qSU2q/) to demonstrate. It also has a solution to change the previously selected marker color back.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your problem, please accept this answer.